# Array Type mismatch in VHDL

Tags: hardware, vhdl, digital

Very simple problem with my VHDL code. I have defined the following code:

```
type irf_array is array(0 to 1) of integer;
signal index : std_logic;
....
index := input(5);
out   := irf_array(index);
```

When trying to compile this simple code fragement I get the following error:

```
Error: array index type mismatch [6.4]
```

So I am wondering if anyone has an idea how I can use the std_logic value as input to my array.

Many thanks!

Comment: Out of respect to those who may want to take the time to resolve a problem that you cannot resolve yourself, I would like to suggest to avoid describing it as "very simple" on beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Your array index needs to be an integer.  If you want to use a std_logic based type, you should probably use the signed or unsigned types (which include the concept of a numerical value, unlike a plain std_logic signal) and appropriate type conversion:

```
type irf_array is array(0 to 1) of integer;
signal index : unsigned(0 downto 0);
....
index(0) := input(5);
out   := irf_array(to_integer(index));
```

You can use a std_logic_vector instead of the unsigned type, with an extra conversion:

```
signal index : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
...
out   := irf_array(to_integer(unsigned(index)));
```

Comment: Why not just declare the index as an integer right away? That way you don't have to convert the datatype later on. signal index: integer range 0 to 1;

Comment: +1 for using proper 'unsigned' types. But I'd use an integer from the outset